# Given this array of arrays, how do I count the number of arrays that include a duplicate element within itself?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[[["Sports", "Soccer"], 2], [["eSports"], 1], [["Sports", "Soccer"], 3]]
```

In any element of the outermost array, the first element (the array) are the list of categories. The second element is the `program.id` this array of categories comes from.

So, taking the first element in the above array - `["Sports", "Soccer"]` is the array of categories for `program_id: 2`.

How do I count the instances of the category array duplicates? In the above case, what I want is something like this:

```
["Sports", "Soccer"] => Occurs 2 times, with Program Ids: 2 & 3
["eSports"] => Occurs 1 time, with Program Id: 1
```

How do I do that efficiently?

Comment: Is the order of the elements within the inner arrays important. For example, what is the desired return value for `[[["Sports", "Soccer"], 2], [["Soccer", "Sports"], 3]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grouped = array.group_by { |s, id| s }.transform_values { |v| v.map(&:last) }

=> { ["Sports", "Soccer"] => [2, 3], 
     ["eSports"]          => [1] }
```

To use it:

```
grouped.each { |k,v| 
  puts "[#{k.join(', ')}] occurs #{v.length} time(s) with ID: #{v.join(' and ')}" 
}

[Sports, Soccer] occurs 2 time(s) with ID: 2 and 3
[eSports] occurs 1 time(s) with ID: 1
```

Comment: I like this, but it doesn't tell me how many instances of each exist. It just reformats it and breaks up the categories from the IDs.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean? It tells you the number of instances by the length of the resulting array. Example `[2,3]`, means two instances, one with ID 2, and another with ID 3.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```rb
arr = [[["Sports", "Soccer"], 2], [["eSports"], 1], [["Sports", "Soccer"], 3]]
count = {}
arr.each do |el|
  count[el[0]] ||= []
  count[el[0]] << el[1]
end

count.each do |category, ids|
  puts "#{category} occurs #{ids.count} times, with Program Ids: #{ids.join(' & ')}"
end
```

output

```
["Sports", "Soccer"] occurs 2 times, with Program Ids: 2 & 3
["eSports"] occurs 1 times, with Program Ids: 1
```

Comment: Hrmm...remember that I want to count the full first element, not the first element within the first element. i.e. `["Sports", "Soccer"]`, not `["Sports"]` and `["Soccer"]`. It has to be the full array with both elements. That's the instance I am trying to count. That's what has occurred twice.

Comment: I edited the answer. But I noticed @casper 's answer is simpler.

Comment: You could simplify to either `arr.each_with_object({}) { |el,count| (count[el.first] ||= []) << el.last }` or `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |el,count| count[el.first] << el.last }`.